# Condition to display document link (href) in WebMatrix Webgrid

Tags: razor, conditional-statements, webmatrix, webgrid

I would like to display a "DOC" link in a Webgrid when a document (path) exists.

The document full path is constructed from a generic path (path data stored in the settings table) and a document specific path (path data stored in another table).

The below will work but there is no condition and  no constructed path !

```
meetingsGrid.Column("Agenda", format: @<a href="document full path">DOC</a>)
```

This does not work:

```
meetingsGrid.Column("Agenda", format: @<a href="generic path" + "document specific path">DOC</a>)
```

Tried this:

```
meetingsGrid.Column("Agenda", format: @<a href="@Url.Action(Path.Combine(@genericpath,specificpath))">DOC</a>)
```

I have tried to add some conditions but even with the full path, I couldn't make it work :-(

```
meetingsGrid.Column("Agenda", format: @if(meetingsData.AgendaPath!=null){@<a href="fullpath">DOC</a>)}else{@Html.Raw("")}

meetingsGrid.Column("Agenda", format: (item) => @Html.Raw((item.AgendaPath!=null) ? (@<a href="fullpath">DOC</a>) : ""))
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

At least in webMatrix 1.0 (I'm not yet on 2.0), you had to explicitly indicate in the format parameter that you wanted to emit html.  Here's a example from my production code:

```
format: @<text><a href="/Dashboard/DealerInfo/@item.Dealer">@item.Dealer</a> </text>
```

Or if your variable could be null, then using your variables:

```
format:  ( meetingsData.AgendaPath.AgendaPath == null ) ? @<text>""</text> : @<text><a href="/Dashboard/DealerInfo/@item.Dealer">@item.Dealer)</a> </text>
```

Which the ? operator says if the statement before the ? is true, return a empty string elsewise return the href you want.

Comment: what are you putting where i had @item.Dealer?  You should be able to put @item.AgendaPath.  Even if item.AgendaPath is null, i believe nothing will be emitted but it wouldn't crash.

Comment: I modified the answer to test for null

Comment: correct, sorry. thought "item" was a dynamic SQL query and "Dealer" the variable "meetingsData.AgendaPath" in my case. Constructed path now works but I still need the conditional statement to avoid "DOC" links pointing to folders (href="@App.documentsPath@Session[CondoName]@item.AgendaPath">DOC</a>

Comment: yes, you're right.  item was a oversight, shouldn't it be meetingsData.AgendaPath ?

Comment: system.collections.generic.ienumerable<dynamic> doesn not contain a definition for AgendaPath ...

Comment: If you think we've gotten past the how to show a link problem in the format: part of a webForm, then perhaps you can close this question, post your code that's giving you problems in a new question.